# How to edit Image metadata in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am using following code to modify the metadata of Gallery Image.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)mediaInfo
{
    ALAssetsLibrary *library =nil;
    void (^ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock)(ALAsset *) = ^(ALAsset *asset)
    {
        NSDictionary *metadata = asset.defaultRepresentation.metadata;
        NSLog(@"Image Meta Data: %@",metadata);
        NSMutableDictionary* dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:metadata];
        [dict setValue:@"sdfdfsfsfsfdsfsf" forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyIPTCKeywords];
        UIImage *anImage = [mediaInfo valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(anImage, 1.0);
        [asset writeModifiedImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:imageData metadata:dict completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {

        }];

    };

    NSURL *assetURL = [mediaInfo objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library assetForURL:assetURL
             resultBlock:ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock
            failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            }];

   }
```

But it is not working. Please help.

Comment: check this [reference link](http://blog.codecropper.com/2011/05/adding-metadata-to-ios-images-the-easy-way/)

Comment: Yes I have checked already but it is not working for me...:(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal example to do it:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *imageToSave = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    /* modify metadata dict */
    NSMutableDictionary *imageMetadata = [[info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata] mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"Inspect current metadata: %@", imageMetadata);
    NSDictionary *iptc = @{(id)kCGImagePropertyIPTCKeywords: @"awesome photo"};
    [imageMetadata setObject:iptc forKey:(id)kCGImagePropertyIPTCDictionary];

    /* Save to the Camera Roll with modified medatadata */
    [[ALAssetsLibrary new] writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:imageToSave.CGImage
                                 metadata:imageMetadata
                          completionBlock:NULL];
    [self performDismiss];
}
```

If you use a metadata viewer (OS X's Preview is good enough) you'll see something like this:

[image]

But, as pawan suggests, use an existing library to do it more easily. Google around, there are quite a few options out there.